# defer() no longer allows the observable return type

Tags: rxjs, ngrx-effects

Today I did an upgrade from angular 6 to 7

Along with it I had to upgrade rxjs from 6.1.0 to 6.3.3 and typescript from 2.7.2 to 3.1.1

And now this ngrx effects method is throwing a typescript error:

```
  @Effect()
  init$ = defer(() => {
    const userData = localStorage.getItem('user');
    return (userData)
      ? of(new Login(JSON.parse(userData)))
      : of(new Logout());
  });
```

> Argument of type '() => Observable | Observable' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type '() => void | Subscribable |
>   Subscribable | PromiseLike | InteropObservable'.

It seems that I can no longer use defer to dispatch an action like this, so I'm not sure how I can write initialization effects moving forward.

I just need to wait for the store to be initialized, so in this method I am deferring the execution until the effects have subscribed to the actions stream.

**Does anyone know how I can work around this?**

UPDATE:

I also found a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-feature-init-effect?file=app%2Fcore.effects.ts) example that leverages `ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT`, but due to the fact that I am in a feature module, this doesn't work ([discussed here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/683))

```
import { ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT } from '@ngrx/effects';

@Effect()
  init$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT)
    .pipe(
      map(() => {
        const userData = localStorage.getItem('user');
        return (userData)
          ? of(new Login(JSON.parse(userData)))
          : of(new Logout())
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a TypeScript limitation. You can work around the problem by explicitly specifying the return type in the arrow function:

```ts
@Effect()
init$ = defer((): Observable<Action> => { // HERE
  const userData = localStorage.getItem('user');
  return (userData)
    ? of(new Login(JSON.parse(userData)))
    : of(new Logout());
});
```

Or, more specifically:

```ts
@Effect()
init$ = defer((): Observable<Login | Logout> => { // HERE
  const userData = localStorage.getItem('user');
  return (userData)
    ? of(new Login(JSON.parse(userData)))
    : of(new Logout());
});
```

The problem is that without the explicit return type, the return type of the arrow function is inferred to be:

```ts
Observable<Login> | Observable<Logout>
```

rather than:

```ts
Observable<Login | Logout>
```

---

Interestingly, although it is indeed a TypeScript limitation, [this RxJS PR](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/4461) will solve the problem and will see the correct type inferred.

Comment: Excellent. I had no idea you could define a return type for arrow functions like that

Comment: Defining the return type of the switchMap operator did the trick. Why is this happening now? Before it was not a problem to interfere the return types properly.

Comment: They would never have been inferred correctly. They were most likely inferred as `{}` - losing type information. Typings have been tightened to better reflect what's returned and in so e situations - like this one - TypeScript limitations might be exposed.

Comment: @cartant do you have a source (i.e. changelog) for the tightening of the typings?

Comment: @Eric On mobile ATM, so looking it up is too tedious. Also, it's possible that it could be due to TypeScript changes. The question mentions different versions of TS. But it's not something that 'broke'. It would never have been inferring correctly. Since commenting above, though, I think TS might have made some advances in inference for this situation, but that could just be wishful thinking on my part.