# Angular 7 upgrade : RxJs switchMap and return type of ObservableInput<void>

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

This code compiled and worked in Angular 6 :

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

switchMap((term) => {
                if (term.trim().length > 3)
                    return this.searchEntries(term); // <- returns  Observable<void> 

                return of([]);
            })
```

After upgrading to Angular 7 I get this compile time error :

```
[ts]
Argument of type '(term: any) => Observable<void> | Observable<any[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<void>'.
  Type 'Observable<void> | Observable<any[]>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<void>'.
    Type 'Observable<any[]>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<void>'.
      Type 'Observable<any[]>' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<void>'.
        Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'Observable<any[]>'.
```

Angular version :

```
$ ng version

Angular CLI: 7.0.2
Node: 10.12.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.0.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.2
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.2
@angular/cli                      7.0.2
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.2
@schematics/angular               7.0.2
@schematics/update                0.10.2
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.3
webpack                           4.19.1
```

Looks like I have to return ObservableInput for switchMap, but how ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add code for searchEntries

Comment: searchEntries returns  Observable<void>

Comment: Same TypeScript limitation and workaround as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52902177/6680611

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @cartant I solved the compile time error with adding return type like this :

```
switchMap((term) : Observable<void | any[]> => {
                if (term.trim().length > 3)
                    return this.searchEntries(term); // <- returns  Observable<void> 

                return of([]);
            })
```